# anti spam field in form

Tags: php, forms

i am using vtiger and recieveing alot of spam on the website contact page i am using this code

```
        <form name="contact" action="REMOVED" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="publicid" value="REMOVED"></input>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="contact"></input>        
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="firstname"  required="true"></input>  
    <label>Phone</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="phone"  required="true"></input>  
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="lastname"  required="true"></input>   
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="email"  required="true"></input>  
    <label><span>*</span>Street</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="lane"  ></input>  
    <label><span>*</span>Postal Code</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="code"  ></input>  
    <label><span>*</span>City</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="city"  ></input>  
    <label>Country</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="country"  ></input>   
    <label><span>*</span>County</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="state"  ></input> 
        <label for="comments"><span>*</span>Description</label>d
    <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="3" name="description"  id="description"></textarea>
```

the isue im having is the submit is to another URL thats not on the site and every anti spam method i have tried (12+1 =) still sends the form no matter the answer

i have deleted the links to the sites

Any help on this would be great

Comment: A common antispam technique is to use [Captcha](http://www.captcha.net/).  That's the random alpha/numeric graphic that you see in most sites.  Also, where is your submit button?  You need to cancel the click or post if the 12+1!=13.

Comment: SHow the form is pointless - you need to show the php code that actual handles your anti-spam measures. e.g. don't show us the box that your broken tv came in - we need to see the tv itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an extra field to the form that you do not use.  Hide it with css.

Spam bots visiting the page will fill all fields, even if they are not shown.

If there's something in the hidden field, the whole form is spam, and you can discard the data.

Comment: This has worked much better for me than a widely used (and widely targeted) solution (especially recaptcha).

Comment: "Spam bots visiting the page will fill all fields, even if they are not shown" This doesn't hold up under my testing. Honey pot fields are routinely skipped.

Comment: did you name it "honeypot_field" by any chance? :)

Comment: I have used this technique and can definitely confirm it works !

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend You other antiSpam method - with token/private key.

In HTML form You put this:

```
<form action="..." method="post">
<?php
$publicKey = rand()%9;
$privateKey = 0.9;
$token = sha1( $publicKey * $privateKey + $privateKey );    
?>
<input type="hidden" name="publicKey" value="<?php echo $publicKey; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
</form>
```

And add also few lines of code before IF condition - for example: fragment with SQL query or send mail, just to check/validate sended token by POST method:

```
<?php
$publicKey = $_POST['publicKey'];
$privateKey = 0.9;
$token = sha1( $publicKey * $privateKey + $privateKey );

if ( $token == $_POST['token'] ) {

// do something, eg: SQL query, send mail

}
?>
```

AND REMEMBER!
Always validate and sanitize all Your input data! :)